# Could a button or tab be added to improve the access to tag synonym voting?

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, tag-synonyms

To access list of tag synonyms, one has to click [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms).

Would it be possible to add a button with this link here (maybe next to the popular tab?):

[image: Tags page]

Comment: yeah ... I like this idea

Comment: The only trouble with making it into a tab is that you already have *two rows of tabs* in the synonym view.  (well one plus the sorting order).

Comment: @M. Tibbits The problem with the current access to tags synonyms is that you have to know the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag synonym link is available on the above page.  It's in the lower left-hand corner:

[image: Picture of Tag Synonym Link]

You just have to know where to look.  It would be nice if this were more visible.

Comment: That is why I had problems finding it. Thank you!

Comment: No worries.  I believe it's a common problem and I like your feature suggestion!